# Прозрачная картинка, верстка

Tags: html

Имеется картинка, на которой на белом фоне что-то есть. Как сделать, чтобы при вставке на сайт вместо белого фона было то, что под ней?

Comment: можно сконвертировать в png с прозрачным фоном

Comment: @dzhioev спасибо!

Comment: Просто открой фотошоп и магической малочкой вырежь все белое. Сохрани в png и по идее она будет прозрачная

Answer (score 2):

А разве нельзя удалить белый фон в каком-нибудь фотошопе и дать файлу расширение .png?

Comment: Ой, прошу прощения. Не заметил, что на вопрос уже ответили комментарием.